# Vue js object property with space is not allowing to put a watcher

Tags: vue.js

I have a formdata object with a property called "Accounting changing". I am able to list the formdata object property in console and do all the manipulations I needed. However when I try to put a watcher on the formdata objects property "formData.Accounting Changing "  I am getting following error:

[Vue warn]: Failed watching path: "formData.Accounting Changing" Watcher only accepts simple dot-delimited paths. For full control, use a function instead.
When I removes the white space it works as expected formData.Accounting Changing.
I need to some how want to keep that space in the property. Is there any way of doing that in Vue?

Comment: Why do you need the space? If you are using the object keys as names the user would see, then you could just do something different, like change the name to Accounting_Changing and have a filter to replace the underscore with whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending on my comment:

> Why do you need the space? If you are using the object keys as names
>   the user would see, then you could just do something different, like
>   change the name to Accounting_Changing and have a filter to replace
>   the underscore with whitespace.

Consider this:

```
new Vue({
   data: {
        formData: {
            Accounting_Changing: {}
        }
   },
  watch: { 
        //Insert your watcher here
   },
   filters: {
      removeUnderscore(name) {
           return name.replace(/_/g, " ")
      }
   },
   methods: { //you can make a method alternatively instead of the filters
      removeUnderscore(name) {
           return name.replace(/_/g, " ")
      }
   }
})

...

In your HTML you can remove the underscore from the key with this syntax 

{{ key | removeUnderscore }}


Or just use the method

{{ removeUnderscore(key) }}
```

Hopefully this helps.